# WPF Columns and Stacking

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I need some assistance achieving the desired layout in my WPF app. My current XAML is listed here:

```
<TabItem Header="Third Party Updates">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Name="ThirdPartyNoManifestTextBox" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="267,22,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=WindowsUpdateCompliance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Foreground="DarkSlateBlue"/>
                <Button Name="CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton" Content="Check for Third Party Updates" Margin="10,11,339,304" Click="CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" MaxWidth="200" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <ListBox Name="ThirdPartyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,70,0,0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                              
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Button Name="ThirdPartyInstallButton" Content="Install" Click="InstallThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="25"></Button>
                                        <Button Name="ThirdPartyPostoneButton" Content="Postpone" Click ="PostponeThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="25"></Button>
                                    <TextBlock Name="MissingRequiredAppGenericTextBlock" Text="Required application update detected:" Margin="12,25,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Name="RequiredAppNameTextBlock" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Item2.Name}" Margin="12,25,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Name="RequiredAppVersionTextBlock" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Item2.RequiredVersion}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Name="RequiredAppCustomUIMessageTextBlock" Text="{Binding Item2.CustomUIMessage}" Margin="10,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Red"/>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="3,25,0,0">           
                                        <Hyperlink Name="Link" NavigateUri="{Binding Item2.TT}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.TT}"/>
                                        </Hyperlink>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="You have used " Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item3.UsedDeferrals}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text=" of " Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.MaxDefferals}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text=" deferrals for this update." Margin="3,25,0,0"/>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

That code yields the following:

[image]

Currently each listbox item (visualized as discrete rows) contains two buttons, and a number of bound properties (application name, version, hyperlink, custom message, etc.). What I would like to achieve is a layout where each listbox item is still it's own row, but split into two columns: Column 0 would hold the two buttons common to each row (Install and Postpone) horizontally stacked. Column 1 would hold the remainder of the controls vertically stacked with that column (visualized as a sort of bullet list). Here is an approximation of the look I'd like to achieve for each row:

```
                                       * Required Update detected: App 1.2
|INSTALL_BUTTON| |POSTPONE_BUTTON|     * "Please install this update immediately"
                                       * https://App1_2.com/download
                                       * You have used 1 of 2 deferrals for this update.
```

Any hints on how to get started with a layout like this would be very much appreciated. Everything I've tried thus far has been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your XAML with a grid and a couple more stack panels, like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Name="ThirdPartyInstallButton" Content="Install" Click="InstallThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="25"></Button>
    <Button Name="ThirdPartyPostoneButton" Content="Postpone" Click ="PostponeThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="25"></Button>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="*" />
        <Label Content="*" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Label Content="*" Grid.Row="2" />
        <Label Content="*" Grid.Row="3" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
            <Label Name="MissingRequiredAppGenericTextBlock" Content="Required application update detected:" />
            <Label Name="RequiredAppNameTextBlock" FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding Item2.Name}" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="RequiredAppVersionTextBlock" FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding Item2.RequiredVersion}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="RequiredAppCustomUIMessageTextBlock" Text="{Binding Item2.CustomUIMessage}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Red"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
            <Hyperlink Name="Link" NavigateUri="{Binding Item2.TT}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.TT}"/>
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
            <TextBlock Text="You have used " />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item3.UsedDeferrals}" />
            <TextBlock Text=" of " />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.MaxDefferals}" />
            <TextBlock Text=" deferrals for this update." />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

I don't have anything to run this against, but here's how it renders in my designer:

[image]

Comment: One additional thing: Depending on how many properties (with values) are read-in, I could have between 2 and 6 bullet points per listbox item. So rather than statically defining the number of expected rows with

`<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>` 

how can I dynamically generate those rows and bullet points (otherwise I end up with extra bullet point rows with no content)?